# How to create Synchronous consumer API for Rabbit MQ in java to fetch message from the Queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want a Synchronous API for Rabbit MQ in java like QueueingConsumer so that I can fetch message from the Rabbit MQ.
But QueueingConsumer is now deprecated. Can anyone please tell me how can I write one of my own.

Reason for Synchronous Consumer - I am writing REST service which will fetch message from Queue and return it as a response.

Comment: try org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer

Comment: See https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#getting

Answer (score 0):

**I.** As I understand, you are using of [`rabbitmq`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) java client.  In this case you should do something like this:

1. Generate `correlationId`, `replyTo` propertiesж
2. Create/Get destination queue/exchange (your destination);
3. Create/Get response queue (your queue for responses);
4. Add `correlationId` and `replyTo` to your message;
5. Send your message by `channel.basicPublish()` to queue/exchange (your destination);
6. Subscribe to response queue by `channel.basicConsume()`;
7. When will you get the response message by `channge.basicConsume()` just check `correlationId` of incoming message.
8. If `correlationId` is match – return received message;

Full code example [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/RPCClient.java).

Also you could find comprehensive answer to your question [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html).

**II**. If you need a ready-made solution I think you could use [Spring AMQP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/) library or any other high-level library. The list of libraries can be found [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html).